# SQL Server : Table Spool when adding ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a very simple query that I am trying to optimize. issues_notes is a simple table, while meta_users is a table on a remote database server that I am querying via a view.

when I run the query without ordering it returns immediately, but when I add `ORDER BY date` it takes about 4 seconds to return. I had SQL Server show the execution plan, and it appears that the slowness is introduced in a `Table Spool` operation that happens only on the join. Is there a way to prevent this "optimization"?

Query:

```
SELECT 
    [issues_notes].[date], 
    [meta_users].[firstname], 
    [meta_users].[lastname], 
    [issues_notes].[note] 
FROM 
    [issues_notes] 
    LEFT JOIN [issues_issue] 
        ON ([issues_notes].[issue_id] = [issues_issue].[id]) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [meta_users] 
        ON ([issues_notes].[author_id] = [meta_users].[userid]) 
WHERE 
    ([issues_issue].[issue_hash] = '%s' )
```

Execution Plan without Order By:

[image]

Execution Plan With Order By:

[image]

Comment: Was there a note about a missing index? like: Missing Index (Impact 83.0193%): CREATE NONCLUSTERD INDEX [<name....

Comment: No But it is giving me a message saying (15 row(s) affected) which is odd since it is a select.

Comment: What is the estimated and actual number of executions against the spool in the slow version?

Comment: Estimated Executions: ~11.5 Actual Executions: 15

Comment: How many rows are returned from the remote query (estimated vs actual). Also what is the source of the remote query? Another instance of SQL Server?

Comment: Estimated Number of rows 256248 Actual Number 95358. The Remote table is a view that selects from another instance of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Table Spool is a "Lazy Spool". That means it remembers rows it has seen, but does not do any extra work. Because the rows coming in on the left of the join are now sorted, repeating rows with the same value will show up right after one another. The spool allows to just reuse them instead of hitting the remote server again.

The sort itself is a blocking operator. That means it will hold all rows before the sort and return them only after the sort is finished.

How many rows are we talking here? What is the total execution time of both queries?

Comment: In this case there are 15 rows returned. The one without the order by returns immediately, The one with the order by takes 4 seconds.

Comment: try to make the LEFT OUTER JOIN [meta_users] a LEFT OUTER MERGE JOIN [meta_users] and see if that helps

Comment: That seems to fix the problem. Care to explain what is going on there?

Comment: Honestly - not quite sure what is going on...
The original query used a merge join and was fast.
The "order by" version used a loop and got slow. With only 15 rows it is very hard to guess what is the problem without looking at the system(s).

Using the merge join hint the requested sort has to be executed after the join, allowing the query plan before the join to stay the same.

However, using query hints is always a double edged sword. So keep an eye out for changes to the performance of this query once your amount of data grows.

Comment: I just saw the comment about the 15 executions. That would explain it: A loop join executes the lower branch for every row of the upper branch. That means the remote query is executed 15 times compared to 1 time with the merge join. The spool actually did not have any effect in this case as all 15 rows were distinct in the join column.

Comment: @SebastianMeine - Depends if the spool was rebound or rewound. Unclear from the sparse details provided by the OP what the 15 executions refers to.

Comment: The 15 executions refers to the row "Number of Executions" in the query plan details for the Table Spool. This breaks down into 1 "Actual Rebinds" and 14 "Actual Rewinds". I don't know if it is relevant but all 15 rows in the issue_notes table refer to the same user in the meta_users table.

Comment: @Amazinzay - So that means that it only did the remote query once, then populated the spool and scanned the spool the other 14 times. How many rows came out of the remote query?

Comment: According to the execution plan the remote query returned 258529 rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith Good point. I will stop speculating now...  --  Amazinzay, you could take a look at your tempdb performance (the spool writes to tempdb), but if that is ok that I really don't know what the problem is without looking at the system.

Comment: @SebastianMeine 15 * 258529 = 4 million rows. Presumably it estimates much fewer would be returned by the remote query or it wouldn't choose that plan.